# Python: in Tkinter, after embedding a pdf, changing that pdf again with tkPDFViewer

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter, embed

So, I managed to embed a pdf in my tkinter window using tkPDFViewer (there is a bug in that library, that I had to fix first).

Now, what I want is that every new search, the embedded pdf changes to the newly downloaded pdf. But  Ihave no idea how to do this.

```
import pdfkit
import smtplib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
BeautifulSoup.features="html.parser"
import textwrap
import codecs
from tkinter import*

# Importing tkPDFViewer to place pdf file in gui.
# In tkPDFViewer library there is
# an tkPDFViewer module. That I have imported as pdf
from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf
x = 0
# Initializing tk
win = Tk()
  
# Set the width and height of our root window.
win.geometry("800x750")
  
# creating object of ShowPdf from tkPDFViewer.

  
# Placing Pdf in my gui.

v1 = pdf.ShowPdf()
def func(event):
    result = str(var.get()) + ".pdf"
    URL = "https://thesession.org/tunes/search?type=&mode=&q=" + str(var.get())
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    lengthvar = soup.find_all(class_="manifest-item-title")[0]
    lengthvar = lengthvar.get('href')
    temp = lengthvar.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    URL = "https://thesession.org" + str(lengthvar) + "/" + temp + "?print=true"
    
    
    pdfkit.from_url(URL, result)
    result = "/home/balthazar/" + result

    
     
    # Adding pdf location and width and height.
    v2 = v1.pdf_view(win,
                     pdf_location = result, 
                     width = 60, height = 20)
    

    v2.place(x = 5, y = 40)
    
var = Entry(win, width=20) 
var.place(x=5, y=15)
var.focus()
var.bind('<Return>', func)

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution though Im not 100% sure what was the cause of the solution. It's from this Question:

[How to make zoom in PDF viewer with Python tkinter and tkPDFViewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70663492/how-to-make-zoom-in-pdf-viewer-with-python-tkinter-and-tkpdfviewer)

Maybe it is by defining immediatly v2:

```
global v2
v2 = None
```

Combined with the conditional destroying of v2:

```
if v2: # if old instance exists, destroy it first
        v2.destroy()
```

Or maybe it is this bug fix he mentions:

```
v1.img_object_li.clear()
```

However it is; it works now for me!

Anyhow, just in case anybody except for me has any interest in a tool to get sheet music from thesession without going to the website, here's my whole code (mind that you need to add your username to the code for the path of the saved pdf file):

```
import pdfkit
import smtplib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
BeautifulSoup.features="html.parser"
import textwrap
import codecs
from tkinter import*
from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf

global v2
v2 = None
win = Tk()
win.geometry("800x750")

def func(event):
    global v2

    result = str(var.get()) + ".pdf"
    URL = "https://thesession.org/tunes/search?type=&mode=&q=" + str(var.get())
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    lengthvar = soup.find_all(class_="manifest-item-title")[0]
    lengthvar = lengthvar.get('href')
    temp = lengthvar.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    URL = "https://thesession.org" + str(lengthvar) + "/" + temp + "?print=true"
    pdfkit.from_url(URL, result)
    result = "/home/USERNAME/" + result
    v1 = pdf.ShowPdf()
    if v2: 
        v2.destroy() 
    v1 = pdf.ShowPdf() 
    v1.img_object_li.clear()
    v2=v1.pdf_view(win,pdf_location = result,  width = 60, height = 20)
    v2.place(x = 5, y = 50)
        
var = Entry(win, width=20) 
var.place(x=5, y=15)
var.focus()
var.bind('<Return>', func)

win.mainloop()
```